# How to get metadata without -g

Tags: c++, llvm, instrumentation, llvm-clang

I'm trying to write a LLVM function pass to do some instrumentation.
Therefore, I I need to get

1. filename in which the function is declared
2. the line numbers (begin and end) of the source file in which the function is decalred.

I already found and tried getMetadata("dbg") but I do not want to use the compiler flag -g.
Is there another way to get these information?

Comment: Why, why, why, why ?

Comment: Why do you need source information for binary instrumentation? Or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: I do instrumenting in an extra pass, so on compiling, optimizing. Depending on this values I insert specific code.

@Stargateur I do not want to put -g everytime and make is as compatible to using clang without my instrumentation pass as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well... the debug metadata is emitted when debug info generation is enabled. You may want to reduce the amount of debug information generated with -gline-tables-only